# Value of a hidden field in a page of forms

Tags: jquery

I am creating a dashboard of user (a page of 18 forms with a hidden input of username in each). On submit I am trying to alert the value of the hidden field. No success.

SAMPLE FORM:

```
<div class="card">
    <form>
        <p>
            <input type="hidden" name="username" class="username" value="admin@co.local">
            <i class='fa fa-user'></i>&nbsp;
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Admin">
        </p>
     </form>
</div>
```

JQUERY (Not working)

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    var username = $(this).find('form').find('.username').val();

    alert(username);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I believe since $(this) is already referring to the form, $(this).find('form') won't find anything. Try $(this).find('.username').val(); instead.

Comment: thanks! That was it!

Answer (score 0):

You should have

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    var username = $(this).find('.username').val();

    alert(username);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```